# change iText to use other JCE provider

Tags: itext, jce

As I know, iText uses Bouncycastle as JCE provider.  I want to use other JCE provider to encrypt pdf.  I plan to configure the Java security properties file to use other JCE provider.  But I am not sure if it is the correct way.   I checked the source code of iText which uses Bouncycastle.  Is it necessary to change the source code of iText to use other JCE provider?

Comment: For what operations exactly? You say encryption... by password or certificate?

Comment: It is to encrypt pdf file by user password. Therefore, only the user with password can open and read the content of the pdf file.